# Array of conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
name, animal, price, type of intervention
Kitty, Cat, 30.50, 1
Ralph, Cat, 12.75, 1
Squizz, Cat, 28.90, 2
Cash, Dog, 34.50, 2
Dexter, Dog, 42.30, 1
Tigger, Dog, 69.70, 1
Molly, Dog, 18.20, 2
```

I want to draw Pie charts according to array of conditions.

```
records <- read.csv("./example.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE)
path="./"
setwd(path)
pdf("example.pdf",paper="a4", width=0,height=0)

name = records$V1
animal = records$V2
type = records$V4
animals=c(" Cat"," Dog")

for (type_id in 1:2){
    nball <- c(sum(type==type_id & animal==animals[1]),sum(type==type_id & animal==animals[2]))
    pct <- round(nball/sum(nball)*100)
    pct <- round(nball/sum(nball)*100)
    lbls <- paste(c(animals[1],animals[2]),pct)
    lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
    col <- c("blue","red")
    pie(nball, labels = lbls, main=NULL,col=col, cex.main=0.8,cex=1)
}
```

My problem is that the code requires "too much" manual input. If an animal is added (e.g "Kangaroo") I would have to add it manually in the conditions.

In a simple approach I would simply loop over animals and append the sum to nball, however it seems to me that R is not made to be used with loop, and that this could be done withtout having to read the data multiple times. Something like:

```
nball <- c(sum(type == type_id & animal == animals))
```

Which returns the total of Cats, Dogs and Kangaroo which corresponds to type_id separately.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting your example to run so it's hard to know what your output should look like -- for instance, the variable "type_id" isn't defined, the variable "sensor_id" isn't used within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understood you correctly. You may have to clarify your desired output.

You could use ggplot2 and dplyr:

```
df <- data.table::fread("name, animal, price, type of intervention
Kitty, Cat, 30.50, 1
Ralph, Cat, 12.75, 1
Squizz, Cat, 28.90, 2
Cash, Dog, 34.50, 2
Dexter, Dog, 42.30, 1
Tigger, Dog, 69.70, 1
Molly, Dog, 18.20, 2")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# filter and aggregate data
df <- df %>% group_by(`type of intervention`, animal) %>% summarise(S = n())


print_pie <- function(toi) {
  pie <- ggplot(df %>% filter(`type of intervention` == toi), aes(x="", y=S, fill=animal)) + 
          geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
          coord_polar("y", start=0) 
  print(pie)
}

print_pie(toi = 2)
```

The output would be the following which you may want to prettify (check [this tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-pie-chart-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)).

[image]

To get a list of plots for each type just do

```
pies <- lapply(unique(df$`type of intervention`), print_pie)
```